# Exe builds from Visual Studio also open a terminal

Tags: visual-studio, opengl

When building and running an OpenGL Solution, it opens the OpenGl window and a terminal. My question is how do I set it so that this terminal appear in my debug build but not my final build?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Debug configuration to use the [`CONSOLE` subsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2017) and `WINDOWS` for Release.

Don't forget to adapt your entry-point (`main()` vs `WinMain()`) if your application framework (if any) doesn't handle that internally.  SDL2 for example handles that for you via some `#ifdef` logic.